# gave forward slashes but still its breaking functionality...any other way for removing `

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, tslint

- I am new to tslint and typescript.
- I am trying to fix this error.  Forbidden Multiline string:
- Can you tell me how to fix it.
- I did some research but not able to find solutions.
- It's pointing to this line

```html
public animals(red, black:string): void {
  $("#tablet").append(`
<div class="" style="`+(source === "sports" ? "display:none" : "display:inherit")+`">
            <div  class="table skychair"  id="tablesky">
              <div class="light chairsContainer listSliderContainer">
                <div class="file file-mouse inactive">
                      <i class="parrot parrot-hen-mouse"></i>
                        </div>
                          <div class="file file-right inactive"> 
                                 <i class="parrot parrot-hen-right"></i>  
                                 </div> 
                                  <div class="chairwrapper listSliderWrapper">    
                                  <ul class="glass glass-tabs list sliderList" id="chairglass"> 
                                     <li class="active" data-tab="plus-tab"><a>plus</a></li>  
                                       <li data-tab="sports-tab"><a>sports</a></li>  
                                         </ul> 
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
          </div>
);
```

- providing code below.
- I even looked at this link and tried but not able to proceed

https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib

**Forbidden Multiline string**

```html
<div class="" style="`+(source === "sports" ? "display:none" : "display:inherit")+`">
```

> Blockquote
>
> (no-multiline-string) app/samples.ts[367, 95]: Forbidden Multiline string: `">...

Comment: @theGleep hey can you update in my code...its confusing

Comment: I think we need more context to answer your question.  Given what I'm reading here, I'm thinking "position the cursor before your ' and push the delete button.

Comment: (Ignore my earlier comments - I deleted them because I realized they didn't answer your question)

Comment: Is the HTML that you've given us in a file that you're importing to your TS code?  That error looks like you have a problem with nested quotes, but I don't see any problems with what you've posted so far.  How private is this code?  Could you post it to GitHub or CodePen or something like that where we can see the entire project?

Comment: @theGleep   hey I am using this html in ts code...can you tell me how to fix it by removing this symbol `...mine is big codebase so its hard to put in fiddle

Comment: "removing this symbol" - my immediate thought is "use the delete or backspace key" ... I'm pretty sure that's not what you're looking for! :) :) :) that's why I'm looking for more context.

Comment: One trick I use to make it easier to deal with a large quantity of html is to break each line into a string in an array, then join the array:  `var myName = ["the", "Gleep"].join("")`.  You might try that as a way to make it easier to see just what's wrong.

Comment: What framework you are using, jQuery, or Angular? also, Angylarjs is not typescript, please fix the tags and the code format, I'm just confused really.

Comment: @Al-Mothafar I am using all

Comment: Ah, that's better!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hah!  There it is!  You don't have a closing `!

Also, since you're using the back-tick quote, you can use template literals - see the code here:

```js
public animals(red, black:string): void {

  $("#tablet").append(
/// revised this line to use interpolation instead of string concatenation
`    <div class="" style="${(source === "sports" ? "display:none" : "display:inherit")}">
            <div  class="table skychair"  id="tablesky">
              <div class="light chairsContainer listSliderContainer">
                <div class="file file-mouse inactive">
                      <i class="parrot parrot-hen-mouse"></i>
                        </div>
                          <div class="file file-right inactive"> 
                                 <i class="parrot parrot-hen-right"></i>  
                                 </div> 
                                  <div class="chairwrapper listSliderWrapper">    
                                  <ul class="glass glass-tabs list sliderList" id="chairglass"> 
                                     <li class="active" data-tab="plus-tab"><a>plus</a></li>  
                                       <li data-tab="sports-tab"><a>sports</a></li>  
                                         </ul> 
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
                                          </div>
          </div>
`          
);
```

Comment: hey even adding closing ` I am getting the same error, any other fixes :(

Comment: yeah...how to fix it...any idea :(

Comment: Did you try the snippet I pasted?  It's a little more than just adding the final tick - it might work.

Comment: No - I also revised the evaluation line to use interpolation.  Third line down.

Comment: Hey can you give comments like which line you added...it's hard to understand

Comment: I re-edited a little bit to add a comment.  With the "``" string type, you can insert `${variable_or_expression}` directly in your string, and the value of the variable/expression gets inserted to the string.

Comment: thanks for your reply...hey I tried with your new code but right now I am getting this error...any idea
  Forbidden Multiline string: ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155839/discussion-between-thegleep-and-ja-ja).